# Is there a way to get the character properties in Google Apps Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to get the `FOREGROUND_COLOR` value of a singular character within a document. I've read the documentation, so far I haven't found a way of getting said value. I understand that the text class can do this; however it only applies to big chunks of text, not singular characters.

Comment: `text.getAttributes(offset)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getForegroundColor(offset)` on a text element and specify a character offset to get the color at a specific position. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#getforegroundcoloroffset

For example:

```
var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
var content = body.editAsText();
Logger.log(content.getForegroundColor(7));
```

will give the color of the 7th character in the document.